# Object as default argument value in class method

Tags: php, oop

Now I have this:

```php
abstract class PermissionModelAbstract implements PermissionModelInterface
{
    public function setDataValidator(string $action, string $method, DataPermissionValidatorInterface $validator = null)
    {
        if (is_null($validator)) {
            $validator = new DefaultDataValidator();
        }
        $this->model[$action . '/' . $method]['validator'] = $validator;
    }
}
```

I want to have something like:

```php
abstract class PermissionModelAbstract implements PermissionModelInterface
{
    public function setDataValidator(string $action, string $method, DataPermissionValidatorInterface $validator = new DefaultDataValidator())
    {
        $this->model[$action . '/' . $method]['validator'] = $validator;
    }
}
```

Is there exists some way to do it?

Comment: That's the proper way to do it. What's wrong with it?

Comment: @onetrickpony , no, it isn't. You cannot construct new instances as default parameters. Try learning PHP. tnxbye

Comment: I was referring to the first code snippet. And I'm curious why OP is seeking a different way

Comment: He want to use a factory/builder, but is yet unaware of it.

Comment: `string $action,` do you have `string` class?

Comment: Yes. I want to have default data validator, which can control access depends from passed data. Good example - control of edit objects, which not created by current user. Or access to different pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No other way of doing it, AFAIK.

If you have many dependencies to the point it gets cumbersome to maintain, consider using a Dependency Injection Container.

Answer (score 1):

I'd get rid of calling `new` inside the method altogether. It introduces tight coupling plus the expectation that a `setFoo()` setter would be called without the actual `foo` is bizarre.

Keep the type check in the signature:

`public function setDataValidator(string $action, string $method, DataPermissionValidatorInterface $validator);`

Then simply provide the dependency "manually" when calling the method:

`myPermissionModel->setDataValidator('foo', 'bar', new DataPermissonValidator());`